# Joomla 3 stored mysql procedure output how to format

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, mysql

It maybe something simple, but I keep trying and can't get it done.  I'm using Joomla 3 with a mysql backend that has a custom made procedure (blogvote(i int)) which returns votes and assigns points based on vote - basically it is a simple code like this:

```
    SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(`vote`)/10) AS POINTS, COUNT(`vote`) AS LIKES FROM `table1`, `table2` b
WHERE b.`id` = `item_id` AND b.`user_id` = p_user
AND `vote` = 1
GROUP BY b.`user_id`;
```

Then I use a custom made module with php code like this:

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld');
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
//display user name and user id
    echo "<p>Your name is {$user->name} and your userid is {$user->id}</p>";
//get logged in user id to put into procedure call
    $userval = $user->id;
    //create query call to procedure
    $query = "CALL blogvote($userval);";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // $result = $db->query();
    //print_r($result);
    $row = $db->loadObjectList('user_id');
    print_r($row);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld');
```

It works now - i.e. I get the likes and points for a logged in user.  I'd like to format it as a table - more or less like I have the output on phpmyadmin

Likes  Points

---

3                0

And now I get something like this:

```
Array ( [] => stdClass Object ( [POINTS] => 0 [LIKES] => 3 ) )
```

How can I get a proper formatting if possible from php module file?

---

I tried some advice that was posted in comments.  Right now I can display user_id in a table but the $result query produces an empty row:

```
echo "<table>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>Name</td>";
     echo "<td>".$userval."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
    foreach ($row as $result) 
    {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td>" . $result->points . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $result->likes . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to just display the results, e.g `Points = 0` and `Likes = 3`?

Comment: I want to display the results as a table with a 2 rows and 2 columns just like what the procedure generates in phpmyadmin.  So top row would be: Points  Likes and bottom row would be number of points/likes so: 0  and 3 (below Likes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the results in a table and use a `foreach` loop for the actual results, like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
        foreach ($row as $result) 
        {
            echo '<tr>';        
            echo '<td>' . $result->POINTS. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result->LIKES . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried something similar - check my question edit, but it didn't produce result table but instead an empty table row:(

Comment: @aretai - Can you try `$result->POINTS` instead of `$result->points`

Comment: Yes it is working now +rep